# Является ли работа с PyTorch потокобезопасной? И в частности метод no_grad?

Tags: python, многопоточность, pytorch

Можно ли использовать методы pytorch в мультипоточных обучениях и в частности использовать torch.no_grad()? Или оно может делаться только в мультипроцессных скриптах?

Сетки на каждый поток можно делать свои, но вот вызов torch.no_grad() наводит на мысль, что там используются глобальные переменные.

Answer (score 0):

Да, является потокобезопасной.

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.no_grad.html
"This context manager is thread local; it will not affect computation in other threads."